# I try to send multiple get request in a loop inside react useEffect. but it gives me an error which says that React limits the number of renders

Tags: reactjs

Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAvatars = async () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        const { data } = await getAvatar(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000));
        setAvatars((state) => [...state, data]);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchAvatars();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

This effect is only run once, so I have to assume it's the effect that is dependant on avatars that is creating too many rerenders. setAvatars is async so you can't use it in a loop like that, you only want to call the setState functions once in a render.

```
const res = await Promise.all(Array.from(new Array(4)).map(() => getAvatar(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000)))));

// Call once
setAvatars(res.map(r => r.data));
```